# What does it mean for something to be "soul"? (as an adjective)

Tags: single-word-requests

> That outfit is very soul!
>
> You look soul today.

Comment: Where did you find those? That doesn't sound right to me.

Answer (score 2):

Soul as an adjective is closely related to the meaning of "soul" in  black American culture, initially as a jazz slang:

***[Soul:](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/soul)***

> - of, characteristic of, or for black Americans or their culture:
>   *soul newspapers.*

Dictionary.comm

***[Soul](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=soul),*** (Etymology):

> - ***"instinctive quality felt by black persons as an attribute,"***  1946, jazz slang, from soul . Also from this sense are soul brother (1957), soul sister (1967), soul food (1957), etc.
>   Soul music, essentially gospel music with "girl," etc., in place of "Jesus," first attested 1961.

Etymonline

Comment: In the usages you reference, 'soul' is used as a noun attribute, a noun modifying another noun. The OP is asking about it as strictly an adjective (note the OP's examples) which has a slightly different meaning.

Comment: @Mitch - I cited  the etymology to give some background. My citation from dictionary.com is as an adjective, soul newspapers. See the link please.

Comment: Josh, cut and paste/link answers need to have the appropriate parts copied. Also, examples that actually correspond to the OP.

Comment: @Mitch - I don't  really understand what you are trying to say. 1) the link and the copied exemple  of "soul"  as an adjective are clear and lead  to the proper site where there is an entry of "soul" -"adjective" and then the example of "soul newspapers". What is wrong, unclear or not useful about it?. 2) I added the etymological part  to add some background to the context. Soul as an adjective referring to black American culture originally comes from jazz music. 3) I answered this question because I think it is interesting and not a common usage. Users might find it helpful.